# Create a powerpoint video player?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, ms-office, powerpoint

Is it possible to create some sort of widget/control which is similar to a youtube video player which I will be able to control in powerpoint. I have worked with the javascript youtube player and I really need to be able to do the same in powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question, but if you want a controllable YouTube player in PowerPoint, this might work:

Create a website with a player and the controls you like and embed the whole website into your presentation using [the method described in this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25946/how-to-add-live-web-pages-to-a-powerpoint-presentation/).

However, I don't know if the solution will be interactive or if it's just a freeze-frame since I haven't tried myself.

Comment: thanks for the information. What I really need is some sort of control I create in the powerpoint ribbon that is a customized video player. Do you know how powerpoint allows add-ins to be created in the ribbon?